# Data reduction and feature maps

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am interested in data reduction since I have 2 million images I need to classify with an SVM.  Each image has 390 features extracted by a CNN. All of the features are floats.

The idea is to produce a subset of say 200 thousand images where I would be able to classify the most representative points on the map.

I am wondering if anyone who has worked in this field could point me to any kind of reference or library which could do this for me.

My current pipeline in in Python and R but I would be interested in any suggestion as I have a .txt with my features and labels.